# Parse router configuration output

Tags: c#, regex, stream

My router supports telnet sessions to configure my router, I want to make an application in c# that parses the console output into something useful.

edit: the lines are seperated with "\n\r" and there are no \t characters used, everything is spaced out

#### Example:

```
 bridge configuration for "bridge" :
OBC       : dest : Internal
            Connection State: connected   Retry: 10
            Priority Tagging: Disabled
            Port: OBC            PortNr: 0          PortState: forwarding  Interface: up
            Multicast filter: disabled              Dynamic VLAN    : disabled
            IGMP snooping   : enabled
            VLAN: Default VLAN: default  Ingressfiltering: disabled  Acceptvlanonly: disabled
            VLAN: Priority: disabled  IP Prec: disabled  Priority: 0  Regeneration table: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
            RX bytes: 1978767922 frames: 21288686
            TX bytes: 481256491  frames: 16224065     dropframes: 13671

ethport1  : dest : ethif1
            Connection State: connected   Retry: 10
            Priority Tagging: NA (destination switch interface)
            Port: ethport1       PortNr: 1          PortState: forwarding  Interface: up
            Multicast filter: disabled              Dynamic VLAN    : disabled
            IGMP snooping   : enabled
            VLAN: Default VLAN: default  Ingressfiltering: disabled  Acceptvlanonly: disabled
            VLAN: Priority: disabled  IP Prec: disabled  Priority: 0  Regeneration table: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
            RX bytes: 44045      frames: 0
            TX bytes: 12618      frames: 0            dropframes: 0
```

Can somebody give me some hints?
My first thought was a regex, but I don't know how to do that on this scale.

Comment: it would help if we knew whether you want all, or just some, of this information.

Comment: What are the separators between items on the same line -- tabs, more than one space, one or more spaces?

Comment: Most of the scripting languages have easy Parsers attached; look at Perl, Python and PHP even to find some. Or if you want to do it in C maybe a flex-bison combo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Into something useful" means to me that your first step is to create classes, structs, and enums that represent your data:

```
public class RouterEntry
{
    public ConnectionState ConnectionState { get; }
    public int Retry { get; }
    ...
    public long BytesTX { get; }
}
```

Then, start thinking about how to parse the result strings.  I would probably write a `Deserialize(StringReader)` method (or something along those lines) so that your object parses the data line by line.

You can also use [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448.aspx) with the SplitOptions overload to help you ignore any blank spaces.

So for example, if you use

```
Port: OBC            PortNr: 0        PortState: forwarding  Interface: up
```

as your input line, and

```
char[] delims = new char[] { ':', ' ' };
```

as your delimiters, then calling it like this

```
string[] tokens = line.Split(delims, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

would result in `tokens` containing

```
[Port, OBC, PortNr, 0, PortState, forwarding, Interface, up]
```

For the lines that have multiple "values" for a key (such as `Regeneration table: 0 1 2 3...` you'll just to take into account the fact that each of those values will be a separate string in the tokens array).

*The key is that if you break your problem down one bit a time, it should become more manageable to solve.*